# (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have seen
[Tensorflow Keras error: Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65438156/tensorflow-keras-error-unknown-image-file-format-one-of-jpeg-png-gif-bmp-re) and [Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191448/unknown-image-file-format-one-of-jpeg-png-gif-bmp-required) these answers. It did not help me completely

I am building a simple CNN in google colab

```
Epoch 1/5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-a98bc2c91ee1> in <module>
----> 1 history = model_1.fit(train_data, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=len(train_data), validation_data=test_data, validation_steps=int(0.25 * len(test_data)))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required.
     [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits/Shape_2/_10]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required.
     [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_31356]
```

I am getting the above error. The error is while I try to fit the model
Using the previous answers that I have linked, I have verified that there are no improper images in my folders. All images are jpeg only.

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create training and test directory paths

train_dir = 'Dataset/train'
test_dir = 'Dataset/test'
IMG_SIZE = (224,224)
BATCH_SIZE=32
# Set up data loaders

import tensorflow as tf

IMG_SIZE = (224,224)
BATCH_SIZE=32
train_data = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(directory=train_dir,
                                                                            image_size=IMG_SIZE,
                                                                            label_mode='categorical',
                                                                            batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)


test_data = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(directory=test_dir, image_size=IMG_SIZE, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, label_mode='categorical')
```

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing


data_augmentation = keras.Sequential([
        preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal'),
        preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2),
        preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.2),
        preprocessing.RandomHeight(0.2),
        preprocessing.RandomWidth(0.2),
        # preprocessing.Rescale(1/255.) Keep this model for ResNet. Efficient Net has rescaling buit in
], name='data_augmentation')
```

```
input_shape = (224,224,3)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False)
base_model.trainable=False

# Create the input layer

inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape, name='input_layer')
x=data_augmentation(inputs)

# Give base model the inputs after augmentation.. Dont train it
x = base_model(x,training=False)

x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

# Add a dense layer for output

outputs = layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax', name='output_layer')(x)


# Make a model using the inputs and outputs

model_1 = keras.Model(inputs,outputs)

# Compile the model

model_1.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

 history = model_1.fit(train_data, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=len(train_data), validation_data=test_data, validation_steps=int(0.25 * len(test_data)))
```

I have downloaded all the images from google search only.
Link to dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dKgzyq2lUF87ggZQ80KUhINhmtVrC_p-/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please just because an image has a .jpeg or .png extension doesn't mean it is good. Some images can have a correct extension and still be bad. Apart from extensions, the image may still have bad binaries which is what makes an image corrupt. You need a code base to properly fish out corrupt images from your directory during preprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue after removing some `.DS*` files and `.*.jpg` files on some directories.

The zipped file contains some invalid graphic files which naming are staring with  `.OOO`